# can't copy/read in right mode from a file to a list

Tags: c, list, addressbook, scanf

i've a problem with read/write from file and view correctly the input:

```
// LOAD THE LIST FROM THE FILE
struct elemento *caricalista(struct elemento *p) {
    struct elemento *punt;
    FILE * utenti = fopen ("miarubrica.txt", "r");

    char nome[MAX];
    char cognome[MAX];
    char telefono[MAX];
    char mail[MAX];

    if (utenti == NULL) {
        printf("non ho caricato gli utenti");
    } else {
        while (!feof(utenti)) {    
            if (p != NULL) {
                punt = (struct elemento *)malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));

                fscanf(utenti, "%s", nome);
                puts(nome);
                fscanf(utenti, "%s", cognome);
                puts(cognome);
                fscanf(utenti, "%s", telefono);
                puts(telefono);
                fscanf(utenti, "%s", mail);
                puts(mail);

                strcpy(punt->nome, nome);
                strcpy(punt->cognome, cognome);
                strcpy(punt->telefono, telefono);
                strcpy(punt->mail, mail);

                punt->pun = p;
            } else if (p == NULL) {
                p = (struct elemento *)malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));
                fscanf(utenti, "%s", nome);
                fscanf(utenti, "%s", cognome);
                fscanf(utenti, "%s", telefono);
                fscanf(utenti, "%s", mail);

                strcpy(p->nome, nome);
                strcpy(p->cognome, cognome);
                strcpy(p->telefono, telefono);
                strcpy(p->mail, mail);

                p->pun = NULL;
                punt = p;
            }
        }
    }

    fflush(utenti);
    fclose(utenti);
    return(punt);
}




// SAVE THE LIST 
int salva(struct elemento *p) { 
    FILE *stream = fopen("miarubrica.txt", "w");

    while (p != NULL) { 
        // Scrive sul file
        fprintf(stream, "%s ", p->nome);
        fprintf(stream, "%s ", p->cognome);
        fprintf(stream, "%s ", p->mail);
        fprintf(stream, "%s \n", p->telefono);

        p = p->pun;
    } 

    fflush(stream);
    fclose(stream);

    return;
}
```

this write me (example)

```
pippo disney 02345432 pippodisney@pippodisney.com
```

in miarubrica.txt but when i read it with a method that read lists (it works), i see

```
pippo disney 02345432 pippodisney@pippodisney.com
pippo disney 02345432 pippodisney@pippodisney.com
```

two times in the shell.  what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick fix. You've mixed the stuff with "->pun" pointer. I've removed the salva() method since you do not use it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define MAX (256)
struct elemento {
    char nome[MAX], cognome[MAX], telefono[MAX], mail[MAX];
    struct elemento* pun;
};

// LOAD THE LIST FROM THE FILE
struct elemento *caricalista(struct elemento *p) {
    struct elemento *punt = p;
    FILE * utenti = fopen ("miarubrica.txt","r");

    if(!utenti) { printf("non ho caricato gli utenti"); return p; }

    while(!feof(utenti)) {    
        punt= (struct elemento *)malloc(sizeof(struct elemento));

        fscanf(utenti,"%s%s%s%s", 
                punt->nome, punt->cognome, punt->telefono, punt->mail);

        printf("%s %s %s %s\n",   /* print new element */
            punt->nome, punt->cognome, punt->telefono, punt->mail);

        punt->pun = p; /* old list at the end */
        p = punt;   
    }

    fclose(utenti);
    return(punt);
}

int main() { caricalista(NULL); return 0; }
```

Comment: On the first iteration the new entry will point to `p`. On the second iteration the new entry will also point to `p`. Also, if the file is empty, the function will return `NULL`, but perhaps it should return `p` instead.

Comment: It should still return `p`. After all, if the file doesn't exist then it returns `p`.

Comment: Here's the line:  if(!utenti) { printf("non ho caricato gli utenti"); return p; }

Comment: It returns p, I've just compressed the source to the single line to make things shorter. I've already told that I appreciate your comment about "return p".

Comment: I'm talking about the `return(punt);` at the end of the function.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then we might just initialize the 'punt' with 'p' at the beginning. If the file is empty, punt will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

In `caricalista` there appears to be some confusion about whether you're prepending (putting the new entry *before* the one pointed to by `p`) or appending (put the new entry *after* the one pointed to by `p`).

For example, if `p` isn't `NULL`, it does `punt->pun = p;`, leaving `p` unchanged, but then on the next iteration it does the same.

Also, if the file is empty, it will return `punt` uninitialised.